# Results for GP2Y1010AU0F Dust Sensor

Tags: sensors, code-optimization, code-review

I am using Dust Sensor GP2Y1010AU0F

I downloaded the code from the manufacturer here:
http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Dust_Sensor

```cpp
/*********************************************************************************************************
*
* File                : DustSensor
* Hardware Environment: 
* Build Environment   : Arduino
* Version             : V1.0.5-r2
* By                  : WaveShare
*
*                                  (c) Copyright 2005-2011, WaveShare
*                                       http://www.waveshare.net
*                                       http://www.waveshare.com   
*                                          All Rights Reserved
*
*********************************************************************************************************/
#define        COV_RATIO                       0.2            //ug/mmm / mv
#define        NO_DUST_VOLTAGE                 400            //mv
#define        SYS_VOLTAGE                     5000           


/*
I/O define
*/
const int iled = 7;                                            //drive the led of sensor
const int vout = 0;                                            //analog input

/*
variable
*/
float density, voltage;
int   adcvalue;

/*
private function
*/
int Filter(int m)
{
  static int flag_first = 0, _buff[10], sum;
  const int _buff_max = 10;
  int i;

  if(flag_first == 0)
  {
    flag_first = 1;

    for(i = 0, sum = 0; i < _buff_max; i++)
    {
      _buff[i] = m;
      sum += _buff[i];
    }
    return m;
  }
  else
  {
    sum -= _buff[0];
    for(i = 0; i < (_buff_max - 1); i++)
    {
      _buff[i] = _buff[i + 1];
    }
    _buff[9] = m;
    sum += _buff[9];

    i = sum / 10.0;
    return i;
  }
}


void setup(void)
{
  pinMode(iled, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(iled, LOW);                                     //iled default closed

  Serial.begin(9600);                                         //send and receive at 9600 baud
  Serial.print("*********************************** WaveShare ***********************************\n");
}

void loop(void)
{
  /*
  get adcvalue
  */
  digitalWrite(iled, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(280);
  adcvalue = analogRead(vout);
  digitalWrite(iled, LOW);

  adcvalue = Filter(adcvalue);

  /*
  covert voltage (mv)
  */
  voltage = (SYS_VOLTAGE / 1024.0) * adcvalue * 11;

  /*
  voltage to density
  */
  if(voltage >= NO_DUST_VOLTAGE)
  {
    voltage -= NO_DUST_VOLTAGE;

    density = voltage * COV_RATIO;
  }
  else
    density = 0;

  /*
  display the result
  */
  Serial.print("The current dust concentration is: ");
  Serial.print(density);
  Serial.print(" ug/m3\n");  

  delay(1000);
}
```

My results seems rounded or always returning in certain 'steps'.
(below are my results)
Is there a rounded error in the code or something else that could be going on?

```
The current dust concentration is: 134.84 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 134.84 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 134.84 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 134.84 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 134.84 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 134.84 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 134.84 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 124.10 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 124.10 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 124.10 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 113.36 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 113.36 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 124.10 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 124.10 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 113.36 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 113.36 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 113.36 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 124.10 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 124.10 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 124.10 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 134.84 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 134.84 ug/m3
The current dust concentration is: 124.10 ug/m3
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because the resolution of the analog read is 10 bits or 1024 discrete values.

In your code the density is basically calculated as:

```
density = (((5000 / 1024.0) * analog_value * 11) - 400) * 0.2
```

You can calculate the resolution as:

```
(5000 / 1024.0) * 11 * 0.2
```

and you get `10.7421875`, which matches your observation.

If your filtering (calculating the average over last 10 values), would calculate and return a float, you would get smoother values.